# Moving App from Sandbox to Production

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Hi We have developed a Salesforce1 Lightning Application in Organisation Sandbox. We have a release in February so that the App can be used by some of our Pilot users. Do we need to create any test classes . How about the Code coverage ? We have lot of lightning components, Apex classes that eare used for developing the Lightning Application.

Comment: Code coverage is not enforced for anything written client side. The platform only enforces the 75% coverage on APEX. That said, please, please, please do not push it out without client side unit tests. How else will you be able to verify the app does what you say it does before anyone uses it?

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1 :** 
AppExchange apps should be installed into production directly from the AppExchange.  They cannot be promoted from sandbox using deployment tools.  This is true for both managed and unmanaged packages.

**OPTION 2 :**
If you still want to do it - then
A change set contains customizations to components such as apps, objects, reports or email templates. You can use change sets to move customizations from one organization to another.

Step 1) Create [Outbound Change Set](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=t_changesets_outbound.htm&language=en_US) and Add your app into this.
        Make sure each component of your app is added into this. (salesforce does not add all by default with app) Check all your Apex Classes & VF's also added into change set.
**Code coverage :** You need to have at least 75% code coverage for all the Classes, Triggers (any Apex Code) in change set (as well as in production).

Step 2) [Upload it into the Production](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_outbound_init_deploy.htm&language=en_US) : A deployment connection is automatically created between all related organizations whenever a sandbox is created.

**NOTE :**

You need to first connect your sandbox to production org by :
(Production Org Setup)
Setup > App Setup > Deploy > Deployment Connection > Allow Inbound Change Set.

(Sandbox Org Setup)
Setup > App Setup > Deploy > Outbound Change Set > Create new change set > You have to include the component manually which you want to send to production, they will not automatically get added to change set.

[WANT MORE/LEARN/KNOW WHY THIS/THAT? CLICK HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/alm_deployment?title=page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster)

Comment: The App we have developed is internal to our organisation. We have over 1000 + users  who will use use this App. We don't want to publish this app on App Exchange, as this app is strictly developed for our Business Usecase.

Comment: When we move Apex classes from sandbox to Production , We usually write Test classes for them to pass the Test coverage of 75%. Do we have any such kind of conditions for moving the lightning  components , apps to deploy it to the Production

Comment: @Rann - Yes you should right Unit Test Classes.

Comment: Go for Second Option then - Updated Answer.

Please accept, if you got your answer, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage is not enforced for anything written client side. The platform only enforces the 75% coverage on APEX. That said, please, please, please do not push it out without client side unit tests. How else will you be able to verify the app does what you say it does before anyone uses it?